Are paths homotopic?
I'm studying topology and a question has come to my mind.
While there's a general notion of homotopy between continuous functions, I've seen there's a more specific notion of path-homotopy defined for paths (in the same space and) having equal corresponding extremities.
The teacher mentioned that this latter notion is introduced also due to the fact that any two path in the same space are homotopic according to the general definition. Is that true?

@geetha290krm Any two paths in the same path-component of any space are homotopic as functions since the unit interval is contractible.

You can always consider relative homotopy. A homotopy of maps $X\to Y$ relative to $A\subset X$ is some $F:X\times I\to Y$ which is constant when restricted to $A$. With the fundamental groups and consideration of paths, we usually care about homotopies on $I$ relative to $\partial I=\{0,1\}$. I just wanted to mention this is a more general notion and not an ad hoc fix for paths.
We care because holding the endpoints fixed makes things much more interesting. Just intuitively it's important but practically, as your teacher notes, if we allow movement of endpoints everything is trivial. $I$ is contractible, so any map $I\to Y$ is nullhomotopic. Any other map $I\to Y$ is also nullhomotopic. And if these are paths beginning from the same point $y_0$, then any two paths out of $y_0$ will be homotopic to the constant map to $y_0$ so ! any two paths sharing $y_0$ as an endpoint will be homotopic.
Explicitly, say $\gamma,\gamma':I\to Y$ both begin at $y_0$. Then: $$\Gamma:I\times I\to Y\\\Gamma(s,t):=\begin{cases}\gamma(s(1-2t))&0\le t\le\frac{1}{2}\\\gamma'(s(2t-1))&\frac{1}{2}\le t\le1\end{cases}$$Would be a homotopy twixt $\gamma$ and $\gamma'$. I have defined things piecewise, so due diligence asks me to check continuity at the boundary; does everything glue? Well, yes it does because at time $t=\frac{1}{2}$ both pieces of the definition are constantly equal to $\gamma(0)=y_0=\gamma'(0)$ for all $s$.
You can extend that to a remark about the path connected components of $Y$. As has been discussed on the site before, two paths in a space are homotopic iff. the paths lie in the same path connected component of $Y$ (it suffices to check this at, say, the endpoints).

There are at least two different notions of homotopy.

Two maps $f,g:X\rightarrow Y$ are freely homotopic, if there is a path $[0,1]\rightarrow \operatorname{Map}(X,Y)$ starting in $f$ and ending in $g$. This in particular applies to the case $X=[0,1]$, giving rise of the notion of freely homotopic paths. In a path-connected space any two paths are freely homotopic. Intuitively, shrink the first path $f$ down to a point, move that along a path to some point on $g$ and blow up this point again to obtain $g$.

This is one reason why one might want to consider a more refined version of homotopy, that of relative homotopy. Suppose we have a subspace $A \subseteq X$ and a given map $a:A\rightarrow Y$. Consider the subspace $\operatorname{Map}_a(X,Y)$ of those maps $f:X\rightarrow Y$ which satisfy $f\vert_A = a$. In other words it is the space of extensions of the map $a$ to the whole of $X$. Two such extensions $f,g$ are homotopic relative A, if there is a path $[0,1]\rightarrow \operatorname{Map}_a(X,Y)$ from $f$ to $g$. Note that by definition the value of the path at some $t\in[0,1]$ is another extension of $a$. If you take $A=\{0,1\}\subseteq[0,1]=X$ and some $a:\{0,1\}\mapsto Y$ you recover the notion of paths being homotopic relative endpoints $a(0)$ and $a(1)$. In particular this notion only applies for paths with the same endpoints! With this definition a path between paths (ie. a homotopy) will continuously deform one path into another but keeping the endpoints the same at all times.


Even for paths with the same endpoints the two notions differ. Take for example the punctured plane $\Bbb R^2\setminus\{0\}$ and the two paths $p(t) = (\cos \pi t, \sin \pi t)$ and $q(t) = (\cos \pi t, -\sin \pi t)$. They are freely homotopic (as explained above), but not homotopic relative endpoints.
Remark I chose to write homotopies as paths in mapping spaces, because I think it is conceptually simpler. There are point-set-topological pathologies, which make it necessary/common to define homotopies in terms of products with the interval...

It is not obvious to me how you mean to topologise Map(X,Y).

Yeah, this is the ugly part and the reason why one usually defines homotopies via $ - \times [0,1]$. In the case of locally compact Hausdorff spaces you can use the compact open topology. There are other workarounds (at some point you will learn about convenient categories of spaces). But these point-set-details were not the point of the answer. I still think of a homotopy as a continuous way (aka path) to transform one function into another, even if you have to define it in terms of products when you insist on using the pathological category of topological spaces.

Let $X$ be path connected, and $f,g\colon [0,1]\to X$ be a pair of paths in $X$. Then $f$ and $g$ are homotopic:
Let $w\colon [0,1] \to X$ be a path satisfying $w(0)=f(0),\,\, w(1)=g(0)$.
We define a homotopy $H\colon[0,1]\times [0,1] \to X$, from $f$ to $g$ as follows:
$$
H(t,s)=\begin{cases} f((1-3t)s),& 0\leq t\leq \frac13.\\
w(3t-1),& \frac13\leq t\leq \frac23.\\
g((3t-2)s),& \frac23\leq t\leq 1.
\end{cases}
$$
